# Getting one element to effect multiple images

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a page of tiled images which each have a three state roll over effect. I got it to work for the first image but cannot get it to effect the other images. I know it has something to do with me using getElementById but haven't been able to figure out a solution

Current Code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="test4.css"/>
    <script>
    var clicked = false;
    function onClick()
    {
    clicked = true;
    document.getElementById("myImage").src="images/in.jpg";
    }
    function onMouseover() {
    if(!clicked)
    document.getElementById("myImage").src="images/half.jpg";
    }
    function onMouseout(obj) {
    if(!clicked)
    obj.src="images/out.jpg";
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <img onmouseover="onMouseover()" onmouseout="onMouseout(this)" onclick="onClick()"                                    
    id="myImage" src="images/out.jpg" width="167" height="230">
    </body>
    </html>
```

PLEASE && THANKS

Comment: why don't you use pseudo css classes like :active and :hover? :active equals click and :hover equals mouseon

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation implies that there are many `<img/>` on your page but your code only shows one. I will assume that your explanation is correct and that are many `<img/>` for the purposes of this answer.

There can be only one element on the page with a given id. Any more than 1 and the page is invalid and you will see issues like the one you see. Instead of retrieving by id, give all the elements the same class and retrieve with [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)